# SQL/PHP: Percentage shorten

Tags: php, sql

I have this,

```
SELECT count(males.id) / (count(males.id) + count(females.id)) * 100 AS male_percentage
```

which gives me 100.0000. I want it to show 100 only, how can i do this?

Comment: But how do you want 83.64353 to appear?

Comment: he didnt ask for this. he wants an integer value

Comment: if he wants an integer value, I'd suggest rounding directly in SQL - all SQL database engines support it in one way or another. It's possible to do `SELECT round(..., 0) FROM ...`

Comment: @Nicola 83.6% But i can live with 84% only (using round)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT round(count(males.id) / (count(males.id) + count(females.id)) * 100) AS male_percentage

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php should answer that